# Remove camera rotation after journaling NX Open

Tags: c#, nxopen

What functions in the journal are responsible for moving the camera? I i removed lines of code like this. After that, the camera rotations became less, but the camera continues to rotate and is centered at the beginning of the coordinate system.

```
        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint1 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-16.215898023039518, 10.575585667199768, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter1 = new NXOpen.Point3d(16.215898023039664, -10.575585667199684, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint1, viewCenter1);

        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint2 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-12.972718418431583, 8.4604685337598333, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter2 = new NXOpen.Point3d(12.972718418431734, -8.460468533759741, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint2, viewCenter2);

        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint3 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-10.378174734745263, 6.7683748270078716, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter3 = new NXOpen.Point3d(10.378174734745398, -6.7683748270077837, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint3, viewCenter3);

        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint4 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-8.3025397877962099, 5.4146998616063069, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter4 = new NXOpen.Point3d(8.3025397877963183, -5.4146998616062154, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint4, viewCenter4);

        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint5 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-6.6420318302369541, 4.3317598892850535, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter5 = new NXOpen.Point3d(6.642031830237066, -4.3317598892849629, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint5, viewCenter5);

        NXOpen.Point3d scaleAboutPoint6 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-5.3136254641895464, 3.4654079114280498, 0.0);
        NXOpen.Point3d viewCenter6 = new NXOpen.Point3d(5.3136254641896699, -3.4654079114279637, 0.0);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.ZoomAboutPoint(1.25, scaleAboutPoint6, viewCenter6); 

        NXOpen.Matrix3x3 rotMatrix1 = new NXOpen.Matrix3x3();
        rotMatrix1.Xx = 0.96533429702299545;
        rotMatrix1.Xy = 0.081373321601911852;
        rotMatrix1.Xz = -0.24800822067542638;
        rotMatrix1.Yx = 0.037268825544830277;
        rotMatrix1.Yy = 0.8974566731012108;
        rotMatrix1.Yz = 0.43952537418062437;
        rotMatrix1.Zx = 0.258342272254519;
        rotMatrix1.Zy = -0.43353189321845947;
        rotMatrix1.Zz = 0.86331301850996822;
        NXOpen.Point3d translation1 = new NXOpen.Point3d(-77.49478481461793, -30.874519473708904, -11.259821185011582);
        workPart.ModelingViews.WorkView.SetRotationTranslationScale(rotMatrix1, translation1, 7.8735770643394423);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically every input action (zoom, center, rotate) is responsible for this lines of code. This is affected by mouse, space mouse and keyboard input actions - but it is safe to remove them.

Unfortunately there is no option to turn off the "recording" of this actions - for my part, i try to avoid rotating and zooming around while recording a macro (or at least pause macro recording while doing so).